# Input shape to Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, data-science

I'm predicting the preference of a customer from a set of objects using convolutional neural network. The input is of the following format.

```
Customer    Objects  x1   x2   x3    x4 . .......x15
a1           fruits  0.5  .9   0.9   0.7
a1           veggies 0.2  .6   0.3   0.2
a1        condiments 0.0  .8   0.9   0.0
a1           dairy   0.4  .2   0.3   0.3
a1        pastries   0.6  .7   0.8   0.0
a1        other      0.9  .0   0.6   0.4
a2           fruits  0.5  .9   0.9   0.7
a2           veggies 0.2  .6   0.3   0.2
a2        condiments 0.0  .8   0.9   0.0
a2           dairy   0.4  .2   0.3   0.3
a2        pastries   0.6  .7   0.8   0.0
a2        other      0.9  .0   0.6   0.4
```

and so on. x1...x15 are continuous variables that represent buying habbit of that particular customer at different perios. I have normalized these variables and hot encoded the labels which is objects column. I'm retaining the objects column in predictors as the variables x combined with objects will have a meaning else they are just random numbers. Following is my code that creates X, Y and reshapes X in the format that could be feeded into conv net.,

```
X = df
Y = df.loc[:, df.columns == 'objects']
Y = Y.values.ravel()
#Encode the class values to integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
Y_int = encoder.transform(Y)
#Hot encode the integer values
Y_cat = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_int)

# Generate Training and Validation Sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y_cat, test_size=.3)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

((35000, 17), (35000, 6))
((15000, 17), (15000, 6))

def data_formatting_score(df):
  pred_col = [ 'x1', 'x2', 'x3',
               'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7',....'x15']
  value_col = pred_col
  df_cust=df.pivot_table(index=['customer','objects'],dropna=False,aggfunc=np.sum)[value_col]
  df_c=df_c.fillna(value=0)
  df_np=np.array(list(df_c.groupby(by=[df_c.index.get_level_values(0),df_c.index.get_level_values(0)]).apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
  return (df_np, df_c.index.get_level_values(0).unique())

X_train, indx = data_formatting_score(X_train)
a,b,c=X_train.shape

X_train = X_train.reshape(a,b,c,1)

print X_train.shape
(34952, 6, 15, 1)
```

1. Why am I only getting 34952 columns when I reshape? Also I noted that everytime I run the script the sample size changes.
2. Can we feed data with different height and width (which is 6 X15 in this case) as input to convnet?

Comment: df_c=df_c.fillna(value=0) ... where did df_c come from?  have you tried a regular model first? ie.  a row by row, predicting the object column? you may not get better results with a cnn and having a benchmark may be useful. for #2, you can design a cnn to take any input shape...so 6x15 would be valid.

Comment: it is df_cust not df_c, sorry about the typing error,. I have tried regular feed forward neural network with two hidden layers, the accuracy was really low. Hence I was trying conv net. Thanks for your input.

Comment: in the past, I have found that for datasets like these, other models work better than NNs. I'm skeptical that a CNN would do any better.  That said, in some cases a 1d cnn over the input data works.  I would throw a couple of linear models at it: logistic regression, naive bayes...then a couple of tree models like randomforest and xboost.

Comment: note that using a 6x15 input for a 2d cnn...when randomized, your "6" dimension is constantly scrambled so any cnn filters learned become hard to justify.  As opposed to an image classifier where the structure is fixed.  just a thought.